# Converting individual pieces of assembly to machine code

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to convert assembly to machine code. I have a MINGW compiler where if i type ./convert.exe mov %a  then it should output  0x01 0xc0. I am thinking of using a struct listing each assembly code with its corresponding machine value. At the moment i keep getting errors like "request for member opcode in something not a structure". Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct _Instruction {
char mnemonic[10];
unsigned char opcode;} typedef Instruction;

Instruction instruction_list[] = {
{"mov", 0x01},
{"add", 0x04},
{"sub", 0x05},
{"mul",0x06},
{"div", 0x07},
{"and",0x08},
{"or",0x09},
{"xor",0x0a},
{"cmp",0x0b},
{"",-1},
};

Instruction get_inst(char mnemonic[]);

int main2(int argc, char *argv[])
{

char* instruction = argv[1];
Instruction get_inst = get_Instruction(instruction);

printf("%s  ;  %s",instruction_list.mnemonic,instruction_list.opcode);
return 0;
}

Instruction get_inst(char mnemonic[])
{
int i;

for(i=0; instruction_list[i].opcode != -1; i++)
{
  if(!strcmp(instruction_list[i].mnemonic, mnemonic))
  {
    return instruction_list[i];
  }
}
return instruction_list[i]; 
}
```

Comment: Start with reading [ask]. Then format this mess properly. And having `typedef` after the type specifier is deprecated.

Comment: `instruction_list.opcode` should be `get_inst.opcode` shouldn't it? Same for `instruction_list.mnemonic`.

Comment: `struct _Instruction {...} typedef Instruction;` --> `typedef struct _Instruction {...} Instruction;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, your structure is declared incorrectly.  You should format it like this instead:

```
typedef struct _Instruction {
    ....
} Instruction;
```

I'm not sure why that's not triggering syntax errors, but it's certainly not helping.

Also, you have both a variable and a function named `get_inst`.  You call a non-existent function named `get_Instruction()`.  You probably meant to name your function `get_Instruction()`.

Also, the `.opcode` member of your structure is a single `char`.  Your `printf` statement uses the "`%s`" format specifier to print it.  This expects a string, which will cause `printf` to continue reading past the end of the `.opcode` member, displaying unpredictable garbage and accessing memory it shouldn't be touching.

Comment: Hi thanks alot for your help but a quick question is how would i print opcode then? would you suggest %c?

Comment: @Jim- "`%c`" will print a single character, but you aren't using ASCII characters here so you're likely to get something unprintable.  Use "`0x%02x`" to print a one-byte number in hex format.

Comment: unfortunately in getting an "undefined reference to WinMain@16" error but there isnt much anybody can do about that so thank for your help anyway!

Comment: @Jim- make sure you have *all* of your compiler warnings enabled.  It will help when debugging things like that.